# Facebook graph v2.11: Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today i'm using Facebook graph v2.11 to auto post to facebook but see error

> Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params

My code

```
try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $token);
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage());
    return false;
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Please help me, thank!

Comment: what is your question? just include the correct OG tags in the shared URL. also, autoposting is not allowed. don´t do that.

Comment: My problem solved. Thank you :)

Comment: @binkute please, i have the same problem, how did you solved?

Comment: Simple, you can add fb:pages meta. 
Example: `<meta property="fb:pages" content="135845446997278">`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but suspect that on November 7th the rules changed on the meta properties. I mean, posting worked before with nothing possibly relevant except fb:app_id meta but requires domain verification afterwards.

Comment: Oh right. On November 7th, the graph API v2.10 was deprecated and auto-upgraded to v2.11 ... that's what changed.

Comment: @Honza i'm still get this error. How can I fix this? domain already verified

Answer (score 15):

Setting the picture, name, caption, thumbnail and description manually is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations).

However, there is a recent change in this. From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#custom-image):

> "As of November 7, 2017, link customization is available however the
>   link must be owned by the posting page and a page access token is
>   required. To verify ownership, check the
>   ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts} field on the URL node.
>   See our Link Ownership Guide for more information. For versions 2.10
>   and lower, picture, name, thumbnail, and description are deprecated.
>   caption is deprecated for all versions."

However, this is only available to pages via [Domain Verification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification).

Comment: Thankyou very mutch!
Solved! :)

Comment: Read the entire Domain Verrification document from Facebook. The domain needs to be verified and the page needs to be assigned to it to work.

Comment: @binkute hi, how have you solved it? i've upload my image to my domain www.test.it, then verified my domain using business-manager but I still get this error!

Comment: @RenierDelport hi i still get this error after I've verified my domain with business-manager. then I linked (always in business-manager) page with domain. where can i wrong?

Comment: @itajackass did you ever solve for this? stuck in the same spot